# cakephp only one model get validates

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a form that save to two models. In the controller I call the validate. But it only checks the first model. It will save without validating the second.

It saves to both models fine. Cant see what is wrong, I have used the validate first as recommended.

Controller:

```
        if ($this->Company->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate'=>'first'))) {  // Should ensure both sets of model data get validated
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

View:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('address1');
    echo $this->Form->input('address2');


    echo $this->Form->input('Umuser.username');
    echo $this->Form->input('Umuser.password');
```

first model:

```
/**
* Display field
*
* @var string
*/
public $displayField = 'name';
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
/**
* Validation rules
*
* @var array
*/
public $validate = array(
    'neci_member_number' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please complete this field',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            'message' => 'Members number should only contain numbers',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'length' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 11),
            'message' => 'No more than 11 digits',
        ),
    ),

    'name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please complete this field',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'address1' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please complete this field',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'address2' => array(
    ),
    'county' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'limited' => array(
        'boolean' => array(
            'rule' => array('boolean'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'tax_number' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please complete this field',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'contact_name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please complete this field',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'phone' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please complete this field',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
            'message' => 'Phone number should only contain numbers, no spaces or other characters',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please complete this field',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),                  
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'payment_start' => array(
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => array('date'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
* hasMany associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $hasMany = array(
    'Employee' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'MonthlyReturn' => array(
        'className' => 'MonthlyReturn',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);

public $hasOne = 'Umuser';
```

Second model:
    class Umuser extends UserminAppModel {

```
public function beforeSave() {

    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {

        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $validate = array(
    "username" => array(
        'mustUnique' => array(
            'rule' => array('isUnique'),
            'message' => 'That username is already taken.'),
        'mustBeLonger' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 3),
            'message' => 'Username is required and must have a minimum of 3 alphanumeric characters.',
            'last' => true),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'mustBeEmail' => array(
// code borrowed from here http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php
// thanks to James Watts and Francisco Jose Martin Moreno
            'rule' => '/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i',
// end of borrowed code
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.',
            'last' => true),
        'mustUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'That email is already registered.',
        )
    ),
    'confirm_password' => array(
        'mustBeLonger' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 4),
            'message' => 'Your password is too short, please provide 4 characters minimum.',
        ),
        'mustMatch' => array(
            'rule' => array('verifies', 'password'),
            'message' => 'You must fill in the password field and must match with confirm.'
        )
    ),
    'captcha' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank'
    )
);

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Company'=> array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id'
        ),
    'Umrole' => array(
        'className' => 'Umrole',
        'foreignKey' => 'umrole_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: What data are you entering and what's the validation you think it should be failing on?

Comment: Hi Dave I have managed to get it partially working by changing it to 'validate'=>'only', the user name will now validate. But when the form is reloaded with validation errors the password field has all those hidden dots, even though there is no password so the form is allowed to save without a password, have you you come arcross this before

Answer (score 1):

if you use the AuthComponent, the posted passwords will be automatically hashed. That may explain why you see that dots when the form is reloaded (probably 40 dots btw). What you can do is specify that you want the password field to remain empty :

```
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
        'label' => 'password',
        'value' => ''
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks, G.J. Seems to work. Not fully sure as it now has stopped validating the second model again even though I have  'validate'=>'only', made not changes that I can see, strange

Comment: With validate => only, your models won't be saved but only validated. The default value (first) is fine for your purpose. By the way, how do you know the validation of the second model is not done ? What is the entry you expect to fail and what is your validation rule ?

Comment: thanks for that point on validate first, was not sure what the difference was. Makes sense now. Below each form input a red box appears to say that the field has not been completed. I have validate not empty set in the models for all fields. The red box only appears for the inputs on the first model but not the second. It does save to the second but does not validate so empty enters will go through.